# DateTime.ParseExact for string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string mydate = "2017-08-03";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

But I get:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

How can I format the string as DateTime with the above format?

Comment: If your string use the - as date part separator then your format string should use the same character as date part separator and set the dd MM and yyyy in the same order of your input string

Comment: `DateTime`s don't *have* a format. They record the number of 100ns intervals since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001. If you want formats, then you want *strings*. Don't confuse the actual data and possible *representations* of that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you should specify the date format of the mydate variable.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
```

Comment: and if I want the format for the date to be 'dd/MM/yyyy' ?

Comment: Then you can use the ToString() method, date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
So, use ParseExact to initialize your date object. Use ToString to output another format.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be doing is trying to parse a `string` in one format and return a formatted `string` in another format.

In this scenario the input and output are both strings as a `DateTime` object format is governed by the current culture.

What you want is

```
string mydate = "2017-08-03";

mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

What this is doing is executing the `DateTime.ParseExact` method providing the format of the **`input`** then calling `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` which is providing the output back to a string.

MSDN Refereces:

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DateTime.ToString() Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

[Formatting a datetime for a specific culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx)